How to change the location of a TextMeshPro to fit an increasing size
I am trying to change the location of a score counter (a TextMeshPro) so that it continues to fit on the screen even as the score(text) increases and I can't figure out how to do. When I tried with anchor points it still did not change.

If you anchor it correctly, and use the text formatter, it should always be right.

You can enable 'Auto Size' on your score TextMeshPro Component

I don't want to change the size of the text but rather the location of the score to fit the game screen even as the value increases @OnizukaTN
